# SQL Server : get rows for date and time range

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2008, between

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TABLE_1]
(
    [numreq] [INT] NULL,
    [rangetime] [NVARCHAR](300) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[#TABLE_1] 
VALUES ('2', '2019-09-27 07:30:00.000'),
       ('3', '2019-09-27 21:30:00.000'),
       ('4', '2019-09-28 09:30:00.000'),
       ('5', '2019-09-28 21:30:00.000'),
       ('6', '2019-09-29 09:30:00.000'),
       ('7', '2019-09-29 21:30:00.000'),
       ('8', '2019-09-30 07:30:00.000'),
       ('9', '2019-09-30 10:00:00.000'),
       ('9', '2019-09-30 11:00:00.000'),
       ('9', '2019-10-01 10:00:00.000')
```

I want to select rows in a time span with 09:00 before 09:00. If today is Tuesday Oct 1, then I want everything from  `28.09.2019 09:00` until `01.10.2019 09:00`.

I used the query below, but not getting the required results.

```
select *
from [dbo].[#TABLE_1]
where (((DATEPART(DW,getdate())) = 2 AND (CAST (rangetime as DATE))  >= (CAST(DATEADD(hh,-7,getdate())-3 as DATE)) and (CAST(rangetime as TIME)>='09:00:00')))
order by rangetime desc
```

How fix it?

Comment: *"I want to select rows in a time span with 09:00 before 09:00"* Huh? How can a time contain `09:00` but be **before** it? The earliest time **before** `09:00` is `08:59:59.9999999`, which doesn't "include" `09:00`. What are your expected results for the above?

Comment: On a different note, in case no one has informed you, 2008 is now completely out of support. It's therefore suggested you look at upgrade paths as soon as you can.

Comment: what is '09:00 before 09:00'?

Comment: What are those values, @JohTravell? What do they mean? Should they be in your question?

Comment: "Out of support" doesn't cover it. "End of Life" is the better term. This means Sql Server 2008 no longer gets **any** patches... not even critical security updates. It's dangerous and irresponsible to continue using this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your question was stated, it seemed you wanted rows from *yesterday* `09:00` until *today* `09:00`. That would be this:

```
SELECT * FROM [#TABLE_1]
WHERE [rangetime] between DATEADD(hour,-15,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and  DATEADD(hour,9,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))
```

*output*:

```
6 2019-09-29 09:30:00.000 
7 2019-09-29 21:30:00.000 
8 2019-09-30 07:30:00.000
```

But you wrote

> everything from 28.09.2019 09:00 until 01.10.2019 09:00.

which is a little hard for me to understand ... maybe you wanted rows from *three days before today* `09:00` until *today* `09:00`? A period of 3 days or 72 hours?

```
SELECT * FROM [#TABLE_1]
WHERE [rangetime] between DATEADD(hour,-63,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) and  DATEADD(hour,9,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))
```

*output*

```
3 2019-09-27 21:30:00.000 
4 2019-09-28 09:30:00.000 
5 2019-09-28 21:30:00.000 
6 2019-09-29 09:30:00.000 
7 2019-09-29 21:30:00.000 
8 2019-09-30 07:30:00.000
```